# Rspec match syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, rspec

The first test passes but the other two do not. What am I doing wrong with my syntax? The only difference is `match` vs `eq`. I know I have used `match` before, but I can't seem to find good documentation of it online.

The error I'm getting is: `undefined method 'match' for 1:Fixnum`

```
describe Die do
    describe "new roll" do #TEST PASSES
        it "returns a number" do
            expect(Die.instance_method(:initialize).arity).to eq 1
        end
    end

    describe "new roll" do # error undefined method 'match' for 1:Fixnum
        it "returns a number" do
            expect(Die.instance_method(:initialize).arity).to match 1
        end
    end

    describe "new roll" do # error expected /\d/ got 1
        it "returns a number" do
            expect(Die.instance_method(:initialize).arity).to eq (/\d/)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: The [match matcher](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-0/docs/built-in-matchers/match-matcher) calls `#match` on the object, it works for strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second test isn't passing because `match` works to compare Strings or Regexes to Strings, not Fixnums. Your third test isn't passing because the regex `/\d/` is not *equal* to the Fixnum `1`, it *matches* the String `"1"`.

```
describe Die do
    describe "new roll" do #TEST PASSES
        it "returns a number" do
            expect(Die.instance_method(:initialize).arity).to eq(1)
        end
    end

    describe "new roll" do
        it "returns a number" do
            # 1.to_s equals the String "1" ...
            expect(Die.instance_method(:initialize).arity.to_s).to eq("1")
        end
    end

    describe "new roll" do
        it "returns a number" do
            # ... and "1" matches the regex /\d/
            expect(Die.instance_method(:initialize).arity.to_s).to match(/\d/)
        end
    end
end
```